# How does activeClassName work with Link component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

As in title - how does `activeClassName` param work with `react-router-dom` `Link` component? What does it mean that some class is active? In docs we can find only:

> The `className` a `<Link>` receives when its route is active. No active class by default.

But without explanation what the active route actually is.

**Edit:** okay, now, having understood this, I can see that I could guess this meaning of this phrase. But I still think that was quite confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the URL is same as the `to` of your `Link`, `activeClassName` will be assigned to your anchor tag. Suppose you have 3 tabs:

```
<Link to='/tab-1' activeClassName="red-text">Tab 1</Link>
<Link to='/tab-2' activeClassName="red-text">Tab 2</Link>
<Link to='/tab-3' activeClassName="red-text">Tab 3</Link>
```

If your current URL is `site.com/tab-2`, only tab 2 will have the `red-text` class name, other tabs will not have it.

The above code will render as below when the url is `site.com/tab-2`, so that Tab 2 will be highlighted.

```
<a href='/tab-1'>Tab 1</Link>
<a href='/tab-2' class="red-text">Tab 2</Link>
<a href='/tab-3' >Tab 3</Link>
```

Example [here](https://codepen.io/adamsullovey/pen/RovYde).